# Find and Replace string in site collection

Tags: 2013, powershell

The business has re-structured and one of the old departments has been renamed. I need to create a powershell script that will rename all objects. For example to search and replace:

"oldDepartmentName" with "newDepartmentName"

Is there a recommended approach to do this, and can it in fact be done with powershell?

Comment: What are your objects? Sub site title, library, list titles or items Name or url?

Comment: Yes, sub site title, list titles, document library titles

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a draft version prepared for you. Please Try and let me know:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
   [string]$sc
)

$site = Get-SPSite $sc

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{   
            if ($list = $web.Lists["oldDepartmentName"])
            {   

                $list.Title = "newDepartmentName";
                $list.update();
            } 
    if($web.Title -eq "oldDepartmentName")
    {          
        $web.Title = "newDepartmentName";   
        $web.Update();
    }
}
$site.dispose();
```

**Note:** Since I don't have environment available right now, this is not tested, but it should get to work. Try on test environment first

Code is written to change title of web and lists only and not columns